# binomial distribution with changing probability of success across samples

Tags: binomial-distribution

I've got a scenario question of:

> An economist interviews 75 students in a class of 100 to estimate the
> proportion of students who expect to obtain a ‘‘C’’ or better in the
> course. Is this a binomial experiment?

The question is asking:

> Is the probability of success the same from trial to trial?

The answer is:

> No. If we let success denote a student expecting to obtain a ‘‘C’’ or
> higher, then the probability of success can change considerably from
> trial to trial. For example, unknown to the professor, suppose that 75
> of the 100 students expect to obtain a grade of ‘‘C’’ or higher. Then
> p, the probability of success for the first student interviewed, is
> 75/100=.75. If the student is a failure (does not expect a ‘‘C’’ or
> higher), the probability of success for the next student is 75/99
> =.76. Suppose that after 70 students are interviewed, 60 are successes and 10 are failures. Then the probability of success for the next
> (71st) student is 15/30=.50.

My questions are:

1. why here is not n=75 but n=100, if we are speaking of binomial?
2. why the p, i.e. probability of expecting to get C or above, is not constant across each trial? Why is the value of p floating and dependent on expectations from other students? If each student is considered a trial, then either the student expect he will get C or above or not, which in each case would have probability of 0.5. What are the hidden assumptions, if any, behind such floating value of p?
3. when do I know if I my p in the experiment is floating, disallowing me to apply binomial distribution?

I further researched, and saw:

> The binomial distribution is frequently used to model the number of
> successes in a sample of size n drawn with replacement from a
> population of size N.

4. This says the binomial distribution is drawn WITH replacement in nature, then isn't the answer above violates the WITH replacement assumption in binomial distribution?

Comment: The question you quote is a terrible one for several reasons (not your fault!).  One is that "trial" could naturally be interpreted as "take a sample of size 75," making its meaning ambiguous.  Another is that it never specifies that the students are *randomly* selected, making it an unanswerable trick question. Even assuming random selection, a third problem is that two models could be reasonably adopted: one based on random selection (which *is* Binomial) and another that models each student individually as a random variable, thereby leading to two opposite but correct answers.